# How to create Custom Role in AWS Cognito and get the Custom Role Permission in Spring Boot Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito, user-roles

I want to create custom user role like Super Admin, BGE Admin in AWS Cognito and also want to get this role after authentication and use this role for authorization in spring boot application with spring security.
Thanks in Advance.